# How to get key value pair using awk?

Tags: shell, awk

I have txt file with following value

```
f:0
c:Test C
s:test S
ctype:0
a:test A
t:10
r:test r

f:0
c:Test C1
s:test S1
ctype:1
a:test A1
t:10
r:test r

f:20
c:Test C
s:test S
ctype:2
a:test A1
t:0
r:test r
```

I have tried the following code but it is not giving proper output as all single newline value as key value pair and loop double new line:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
    FS="\n"
    RS=""
}
{
    print $1 "\n " $2 "\n" $3
}
```

Can use anything than awk.

**EDIT:**

*OUTPUT would be like:*

```
if(ctype==0){
execute c;
}else if(ctype==1){ execute a}
```

I want to loop the data and perform an action.

Comment: `awk -F: 'NF{print $1, $2}' file`

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Showing us a command that doesn't do what you want and telling us it doesn't do what you want doesn't go very far towards telling us what it is you DO want!

Comment: If you need help with this problem then you should clarify your question.

Comment: `RS="\n\n"` and `FS="\n"` maybe??? The expected output isn't clear

Comment: Edited  the question above!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I understand your question, but is this close to what you have in mind:

```
{
    if ( /^a:/ ) a = substr($0, 3)
    if ( /^c:/ ) c = substr($0, 3)
    if ( /^ctype:/ ) ctype = substr($0, 7)
    if ( /^$/ ) {
        if ( ctype == "0" ) {
            print "a: [", a, "]"
        } else {
            print "c: [", c, "]"
        }
    }
}
END {
    if ( ctype == "0" ) {
        print "a: [", a, "]"
    } else {
        print "c: [", c, "]"
    }
}
```

This reads each block of test, searching for the values of a, c and ctype, and then prints the value of either a or c based on the value of ctype.  That's what the edited part of your question seems to indicate you want to accomplish; if not, hopefully it will at least point you in the right direction.